# Graph API Reference user/inbox missing permistion

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, xamarin

I wanna get inbox from facebook, using xamarin facebook android sdk, as it is documented to get inbox access token needs

> read_mailbox

permission.  But same time this permission is already deprecated. here are the sources :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/inbox
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference

So, I'm very confused, how to get inbox for facebook api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out already, the `read_mailbox` permission is gone. There is no replacement, which means that it is not possible anymore to get access to the inbox. This is for privacy reasons, because an App would also get access to received messages from other users - while they did not even authorize the App.